# RouterLink does not work properly

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have an app that works with RouterLink.

Here is the **imports** array in the **App Module**:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      {path:'contact', component: ContactComponent},
      {path: 'about/:id/:name', component: AboutComponent}
    ])
```

And this is the app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active"> Contact</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

On the **Home** if the user clicks on **About this user**, it should be redirected to a an About page for a specific user:

```
<div>
  <a [routerLink]="['/about', follower.id, follower.name]">About this user { ... </a>
</div>
```

However, when the app loads, I get this error on console: 
*Cannot read property 'id' of undefined*

Could you please help me find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use safe navigation operator as follows,

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/about', follower?.id, follower?.name]">About this user { ... </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check **object key** is present or not by using **?** operator like this:

```
<div>
   <a [routerLink]="['/about', follower?.id, follower?.name]">About this user { ... </a>
</div>
```